# Disable hyperlinks in generated PDF using Puppeteer

Tags: node.js, chromium, puppeteer, puppeteer-sharp

Is there a way to disable auto generated hyperlinks from pdf. For example, I have a string `https://example.com/`, after converting from html to pdf using Puppeteer, it automatically converts the string to an hyperlink, which does not exist.

Is there a flag or something in Chromium or puppeteer to disable auto linkification.

Answer (score 1):

Puppeteer does not add any links to the PDF document that are not actually present in the page. It is very likely your PDF viewer that is adding these links.

**Try it yourself.**

Upload your PDF to [this viewer](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html) (that uses PDF.js), button is in the top right. This viewer does not add any links to the document. If the link is not clickable in this document, your PDF viewer is adding the links.